# Rails: How to dynamically add rows to database through controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

After accepting data through a form for one table, I want to process that data and use it to generate entries for another table. Essentially I will be taking the first set of data, plugging it into a formula, and then entering the result as the entry of another table. Each original set of data generates multiple rows in the other table (as the formula runs several times with one variable being incremented throughout the runs).

In short, I want to do something like this:

```
def show
  @diagram = Diagram.find(params[:id])
  @horizon = @diagram.horiz

  @horizon.times do |i|
    @cashflow = Cashflow.new
    @flow = compute_cashflow(@diagram.investment, i)
    @cashflow.flow = @flow
    @cashflow.year = i
    @cashflow.save
  end
end
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Here is the function "compute_cashflow(investment, year)":

```
def compute_cashflow(investment, year)
  return investment+year
end
```

(it's meaningless right now but I want to test the idea)
[image]

Comment: Of course, code is code. You seem to mean other table, however, not other database. It might have been quicker to just try it. Whether or not this belongs in controller code is a different issue.

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I meant. I have tried this and it doesn't work - Rails doesn't want me to set the data this way. It works when I give constant values, but not when I pass variables.

Comment: Define "doesn't work", Rails doesn't care how the values are set. Check your assumptions with logging or pry.

Comment: The entries are being made in the cashflows table, but their values are all nil, although the values for the diagram objects are not nil. I added the method "compute_cashflow(investment, year)" to the original post.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Use `save!` to see if there are any exceptions. Unrelated and rhetorical, are they supposed to be completely detached from all other entities like that?

Comment: Added a photo; the last run was tried with "save!".

A diagram generates many cash flows, so there's an association there. I don't know how to define the cash flows by the values of the diagram other than through this method, though.

Comment: Would need more info, like the model. But if you're seeing values, it'll save, if nothing else interferes. Please post text for text, not images.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a bit of your time and expertise, Dave. I've decided to put the necessary logic in the ActiveRecord of Diagram, which is working so far. Learning a lot in this project!